# Logout from remote stuck paramiko ssh

Tags: python, multithreading, ssh, paramiko

This problem is related to the [Taking the input from auto-execute user login using ssh execute command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43336007/taking-the-input-from-auto-execute-user-login-using-ssh-execute-command) which I try to do another approach to solve my current problem.

Since the paramiko loop forever in the waiting for user input command. I unable to kill, having pid or do anything to proceed.

```
    stdin, stdout, stderr = self.connection.exec_command(command)

    while not stdout.channel.exit_status_ready():
        if stdout.channel.recv_ready():
            alldata = stdout.channel.recv(1024)
            rl, wl, xl = select.select([stdout.channel], [], [], 0.0)
            if len(rl) > 0:
                self.logger.info(stdout.channel.recv(1024), )
```

Which the approach, I try to login to other user (root) using paramiko and kill this remoteuser.

**In the root:**

```
$ skill -KILL -u remoteuser
```

I try using thread, but since it unable to process. It failed to execute the next thread.

```
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=remoteuser_stuckfreeze)
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=roottokillremoteuser)
thread1.start()
thread2.start()
thread1.join()
thread2.join()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up by using [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/).

```
from fabric.tasks import execute
from fabric.api import run, settings, env

def remoteuser_login(self):
    env.user = 'remoteuser'
    env.password = 'remotepassword'
    with settings(prompts={'>': 'q\n'}):
        run('exit')
```

and to execute that

```
execute(remoteuser_login, host='ipaddress')
```

Also to hightlight, fabric also have command-timeout where we can set this to quit from the remote if stuck.

**--command-timeout=N**

http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.13/usage/fab.html

Answer (score 0):

Alternative using [`parallel-ssh`](https://github.com/ParallelSSH/parallel-ssh)

```
from pssh import ParallelSSHClient
client = ParallelSSHClient(['myhost'], user='remoteuser',
                           password='remotepassword')
output = client.run_command(<..>)
# Can send data using stdin channel if needed
# output.stdin.write('write on user prompt\n')
# output.stdin.flush()
stdout = list(output.stdout)
```

There is a `channel_timeout` setting to timeout after N seconds of inactivity, equivalent of command-timeout.

Proposing a different paramiko using library be used as Fabric is very buggy in my and others experience.